# HTML5 - validate input field using pattern attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I validate a form field upon submission before sending a request to the server that the serial number has this exact format :

```
 <input type="text" id="serial" placeholder="123AB-BCXH3-778F2-90763">
```

(20 Characters, seperated by - for every 5 characters )

Thanks

**Answer**

Previous title was : ***Javascript check string format***

My question was how to validate with Javascript but Joe below gave a good example using regex expressions, I have never used Regex but this what i learned today :

**^\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}$**  Where my Serial format is 5 Characters followed by "-"

- \w => is any word Character  a-z, A-Z, 0-9
- {5} => Count 5 Characters
- \- => backslash causes the metacharacter to be treated as a
  character, here "-"
- $ => end of string
- ^ => Starting position

Comment: No need for JavaScript _or_ jQuery, you can do this with HTML5 form validation in modern browsers :)

Comment: really? any link I can check out?

Comment: Sure, [here's the first google result](http://blog.staffannoteberg.com/2012/03/01/html5-form-validation-with-regex/), basically you can specify a `pattern` attribute on `input` elements

Comment: great benjamin! Will definitely do it with HTML

Comment: When you do, please consider posting your solution as an answer so future visitors will know how to solve it. Good luck!

Comment: Sure Will do Benjamin. Let me dig through the documentation first. Thanks!

Comment: They are not all digits by the way.

Comment: @putvande, sure everyone noticed, it;'s not the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [functional fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/9WQ4R/)

```
<form>
    <input type="pid"  id="pid" maxlength="23" pattern="^\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5}$" required value="123AB-BCXH3-778F2-90763" size="35"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The size property was just to be able to see the whole code.

Comment: Thanks Joe, very helpful approach. Answer added above.

Answer (score -1):

A JavaScript solution would be to use regular expressions to validate your input against before validating.

In your form use the `onsubmit` to make a call to a validation method, something like:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validate();" >
   <input type="text" name="myinput" id="serial" placeholder="123AB-BCXH3-778F2-90763">
</form>
```

Your validate method should look something like this:

```
function validate() {
    var input =  document.myform.myinput.value;
    var regExp = "^\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5}\-\w{5}$";
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (match){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Not valid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

So this will prevent the user from posting unless the input is acceptable.

Comment: What is the regexp for it?

Comment: I don't really know, I'm not a Regexp specialist.

Comment: The regex I made in my answer would work here as well.